# Mysql script to delete ascii code from Dec 16 to 31

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong with this script? I was actually trying to delete all ASCII code from 16 to 31 using a script. I have developed a script for selecting it.

```
SELECT * from `TABLE_NAME` WHERE COLUMN_NAME like %(ascii code here)%
```

But How do I delete it. Is this code right?

```
DELETE from `TABLE_NAME` WHERE .....(dont know what to say here)
```

Comment: What are you trying to delete from? This looks sort of like the `information_schema` database, but it doesn't have a table called `TABLE_NAME` (that's the name of a column).

Comment: And if so, `information_schema` is read-only. You can't alter tables by writing to it.

Comment: Actuall im trying to delete ascii number 16 which is DLE all the way to 31 which is US. table name is actually ANIMALS and column name is description. There are ascii codes such as 24 which is DLE which is included on some data and I want to remove it. Thanks.

Comment: I just made that database so My apologies for using animals as a test subject. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE command removes WHOLE row from a table. I guess you want to remove special characters from the string `DESCRIPTION` not a row. Then you should use UPDATE statement and [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function.

For example if you want to delete ASCII code `16` then use the following statement:

```
UPDATE Animals 
   SET Description = REPLACE(Description,CHAR(16),'')
   WHERE Description LIKE CONCAT('%',CHAR(16),'%');
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1acb2/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I got this script and use this as a solution to my problem above.

To Search I use the script below.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name REGEXP '[[.DLE.]-[.US.]]'
```

And this is for the update. Slow but sure, I want to to make sure that all non keyboard characters deleted.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name(REPLACE(column_name,Char(16), '')
```

Above script is for DLE only so you have to change 16 all the way down to 31 to update and replace all non keyboard character ranging from DEC 16 to DEC 31.

Comment: UPDATE statement is slow because you UPDATE all rows not only where symbols exists. You should add WHERE condition from your first query to the UPDATE to make it faster and update only what you really need.